# Use newly sampled validation examples with TensorFlow Keras fit when using `validation_steps`?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

TensorFlow's Keras `Model.fit` method has two parameters to limit the number of steps during a training epoch: `steps_per_epoch` for the number of training steps and `validation_steps` for the number of validation steps. However, a major difference between these two arguments (besides being for training or validation) is how they sample from the dataset. For training, `steps_per_epoch` will use the next available samples each epoch, and so each epoch progresses further through the dataset. For validation, `validation_steps` will always start from the beginning of the validation. The reason `validation_steps` is set to work differently is because the developers wanted to ensure the same data is used for each validation run. In my case, I would prefer this wasn't how `validation_steps` worked. My dataset (both training and validation) is quite large, and I would like to validate frequently, and not have it take an excess time. However, I also don't want to validate on only a limited validation dataset. I would like the validation to just sample a random subset of the total dataset for each validation run, so that the smoothed validation curve will give an overall approximation. This would be possible by shuffling the entire validation set, but again, as the dataset is very large all the file paths of the examples can not be loaded into memory simultaneously to be shuffled.

Is there a way to have `validation_steps` work the same as `steps_per_epoch` in that the data used continually progresses through the dataset on each epoch? Either by some setting of `fit` or by somehow wrapping the dataset in such a way that when `fit` tries to reset the dataset, it instead samples the next elements in the dataset?

Just to clarify, my data pipeline starts with a `pathlib.Path.glob`. This produces a generator. This generator cannot be converted to a list as there are too many paths to fit in memory at once. This generator is used as the source of a TensorFlow `Dataset`. Through the Dataset API, I load individual files and preprocess them. The API does this asynchronously from the GPU, using multiple processes. The Dataset API also shuffles a small buffer of the loaded examples. This provides a steady supply of prefetched data for the GPU to train on.

Comment: I don't know your datasets, but I know that validation is used to avoid overfitting. so, a huge datasets for it may not be beneficial (to the training process). If you have too much data, you can enhance the structure of your model everytime and then train it with a new validation set. thus avoiding another problem (data leakage)

Comment: How are you feeding the validation data? Is it through a generator?

Comment: @rvinas, with a generator function passed to `Dataset.from_generator`, which then produces a new generator on each epoch.

Comment: Why do you create a dataset `from_generator` if you already have a generator? Is it a Keras generator or is it a `yield` generator?

Comment: @DanielMöller, it's a Python generator coming from `pathlib.Path.glob`. I'm creating the TensorFlow `Dataset` object to take advantage of several of the Dataset API tools during preprocessing.

Comment: If you know the size of the dataset, say N, and the number of samples you want to use to validate, say K, can't you just use `np.random.choice`?

Comment: @rvinas, sorry, in my original question, I had mentioned two restrictions, one where the paths are too large to shuffle, and one where all the paths can not fit into a list in memory simultaneously. For the case where I can fit them all into memory, but shuffling is impractical, `np.random.choice` would probably suit the job. However, as I'll end up using the solution for not being able to fit the list in memory for both cases, I adjusted my question to focus on that case. In that case, `np.random.choice` won't be available since I can't index the generator (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: Can you **fully** describe what is output by the original generator? How many arrays per yield? X, Y?  Batch size? Type? etc.

Comment: @DanielMöller, the original function being handed to the Dataset API just returns a `pathlib.Path.glob` generator. The function which creates the generator is what is being given to the `Dataset.from_generator`. Each yield is a single file path. The Dataset API is being used to do the buffered shuffling, file loading, preprocessing, batching, prefetching, etc.

Comment: Don't give the function, give the generator. If you use `fit` , most of these things will be done normally. It's not exclusive for `Dataset`.

Comment: Following the idea of `np.random.choice`, if you know N and K, could you rename all the files by enumerating them with numbers from 1 to N? Then, after drawing K random integers from [0, N),  with `pathlib.Path.glob` you could load just the files corresponding to those K indices.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which kind of generator you're using.

If it's a `keras.utils.Sequence` (the standard Keras generator that you get with `ImageDataGenerator` and methods like `flow_from_dataframe`, `flow` etc.), these have a `len` property and can have their batches gotten by index.

So, for these you create an array of indices:

```
batches = len(val_generator)
indices = np.arange(batches)
```

You can then create your own **Python** generator like:

```
def my_gen(val_generator):
    batches = len(val_generator)
    indices = np.arange(batches)

    while True: #these non standard generators using "yield" must be infinite

        #shuffle the batches
        np.random.shuffle(indices)

        #iterate the indices:
        for i in indices:
            yield val_generator[i]
```

Fit with your new "untouchable" generator. Keras can't start it over because this option doesn't exist.

```
model.fit(.... validation_data = my_gen(val_generator), validation_steps = choose)
```

---

If it's already a Python generator (that uses `yield`), you can be sure Keras is not resetting it, it's not possible. It's a custom generator and all you need is to shuffle your data each cycle, just like above. But instead of shuffling the entire data, shuffle indices. Pretty much the same that I did above, but instead of getting from the Keras generator, get from the data.

```
def my_gen(dataX, dataY, batch_size):
    samples = len(dataX)
    indices = np.arange(samples)

    batches = samples // batch_size
    if samples % batch_size > 0:
        batches += 1

    while True:
        np.random.shuffle(indices)

        for b in range(batches):
            start = b * batch_size
            end = (b+1) * batch_size

            batchX = dataX[indices[start:end]]
            batchY = dataY[indices[start:end]]
            yield batchX, batchY
```

Comment: It's a Python generator. Note that the _list of paths_ to the files of the dataset is too large to fit in memory. So I cannot load the dataset to index it, nor load the file paths to index them. Still the second method may be doable, with an outer generator producing the inner generator, then iterating to a random position of the inner generator to be the output for the outer generator. Though this still has some additional challenges (predetermining the size to allow random iteration of, having to slowly iterate through an enormous dataset to get to the start point, etc)

Comment: Ok, then just use the generator, don't use the Dataset.

Comment: Trying to iterate to a random position is not a good idea, it will take the entire time it takes to load all batches until you get there.

Comment: For not using Dataset API and just using the generator, do you mean to build all the Dataset API functionality from scratch? I'm using a large number of tools from that API. The multicore data preprocessing, buffered shuffle, asynchronous prefetching, etc. Building these from scratch is not particularly trivial. Or were you suggesting to replace the Dataset API with something else?

Comment: I realized I should probably describe my data pipeline slightly better. I've added a paragraph to the original question. The generator is only suppling the the list of file paths to the Dataset API. All the data loading, preprocessing, prefetching, etc is done by the Dataset API to efficiently ensure a constant supply of training data is ready for the GPU.

Comment: If that glob is a generator, tensorflow doesn't have the power to reset it, unless you're not passing the generator, but a creator for the generator.

Comment: To be honest, I'm usually very satisfied with `fit(generator, workers = many)`, it does parallel fetching.